# Как сделать приложение для работы с SMS

Tags: android, sms

Хотелось бы сделать приложение, которое просматривало SMS сообщения, собирало их, и отправляло куда либо (все равно куда, лишь бы я имел доступ). Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

[Пример чтения SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-device-programmatically-in-android).

Доступ к SMS требует разрешений, поэтому не забудьте добавить в Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Также позаботьтесь о получении [разрешения от пользователя](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

Ну и чтобы отправить SMS используйте [SmsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager).